# web service for an ionic App

Tags: web-services, ionic-framework

I need help please,I want to create a mobile app with ionic for fitness,my problem is that I didn't found on the net a Fitness Web service,have you please any good one
thanks for help

Comment: Mind explaining your question in detail ?

Comment: hi Hardik,in fact I want to create a Fitness App with an existing web service for the last Fitness news,I didn't found a good one on net

Comment: my question isnis it possible to get this type of web services on the net thanks